# R - tapply produces NULL on empty cells

Tags: r

Is there an elegant way to make tapply *not* return NULL on empty cells? (From ?tapply: "For a list result, the elements corresponding to empty cells are NULL.")

i.e. with

```
v1 = factor(rep(c(1,3),3),levels = 1:3)
v2 = factor(c("A","B","B","A","A","B"),levels=c("A","B"))
tapply(v2,v1,table)
```

I get

```
$`1`

A B 
2 1 

$`2`
NULL

$`3`

A B 
1 2
```

while the desired output would be

```
$`1`

A B 
2 1 

$`2`

A B 
0 0 

$`3`

A B 
1 2
```

Thanks!

Comment: In your example you should use `table(v1,v2)`. There is no need for `tapply`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an approach using `split` and `lapply` instead of `tapply`

```
> lapply(split(v2, v1), table)
$`1`

A B 
2 1 

$`2`

A B 
0 0 

$`3`

A B 
1 2
```